# Why is this optocoupling circuit useless?

Tags: opto-isolator

Could someone explain me why I can't use the same ground when optocoupling?

[image: img]

How can the uC get damaged if there is a short circuit in the phototransistor side?

Comment: You can use the same ground but you don't have to AND if there is a short on the phototransistor it won't damage the uC. Don't know what your problem is dude.

Comment: The problem with having the same ground for the opto-coupler and the phototransistor part of the circuit is that you won't have [galvanic isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_isolation) between the two circuits, if that is what's important for you.

Answer (score 7):

The entire point of the a optocoupler is to allow electrical separation of a circuit. It's literally a led, a little tube, and a phototransistor. You could make one yourself. You don't have to share a common ground, but you can if you want.

As for a short on the phototransistor size, for most circuits, especially low voltage low current ones you have nothing to worry about. Unless you connect a high voltage high current line that way exceeds the optocoupler's absolute maximum specs, enough that they cause the optocoupler to melt/explode/catch on fire.

Comment: My preferance for a new design is to always have the micro isolated with opto's. When the unexpeted happens the micro's are much more likely to survive. If I can't use opto's it's because of cost and / or space limitations and / or some requirement. Inputs get the same treatment as well. Having had multiple 96 way IO interface cards on Test PC's fried in one go, just because of a wiring error I have got very defensive in IO designs.

Answer (score 3):

> > Could someone explain me why I can't use the same ground when optocoupling?

If you are looking for Galvanic Isolation which is basically the purpose when using optocouplers or SSR (Solid State Relays), no you should not use same ground on both sides. But if you are not looking for Galvanic Isolation there is no prohibition of using same ground both sides.

> > How can the uC get damaged if there is a short circuit in the phototransistor side?

No, the microcontroller will not get damaged even if there is a short in the phototransistor side. If short circuit occurs on transistor side, it will affect the 5.0V supply but not the 3.3V supply (assuming you are not generating 3.3V from 5.0V). But let's say you are generating 5.0V to generate 3.3V, then your regulator or DC DC converter gets affected in case of short circuit but still your microcontroller is safe.

Comment: I don't know if what I need is galvanic isolation. I want the uC not to get damaged if there is an overcurrent or overvoltage in the phototransistor circuit. For example, if I'm driving a relay or DC motor with 12V and 80mA, none of those values can be present at the uC pin.
I'm considering that the 12V and the 3.3V come from voltage regulators connected to the same transformer.

Comment: If you don't need isolation, then there are cheaper and faster ways to get protection, like driver ICs